# Animate individual div sharing same class

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am having some trouble getting the animate function to work on specific divs. I am displaying x amount of videos on a page. Each video has a class named that displays a description below it. I have another div to the right of the text that has a background image signifying an icon for the user to click to expand the description. When it is clicked, the description expands a defined number of pixels in height. This code works fine, however when you click the icon to expand it, it expands all the videos descriptions since they're sharing the same class. I do not want to have to use different ID's because that will get out of control when there are hundreds of videos. I am new to jQuery, but have researched traversing and trying to use parent and closet, I feel like this is how it may be achieved but cannot wrap my head around it. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="video">
   <div class="text">Text text</div>
   <div class="icon"><a class="clickme"></a></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.clickme').toggle(function() {
        $('.text').animate({height:'100px'});
    }, 
    function() {
        $('.text').animate({height:'40px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toggle function used that way is [**deprecated and removed**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), you need some sort of flag, and you need to target each `.text` element, not all of them :

```
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    var elem = $(this).closest('.video').find('.text');

    if (elem.data('state')) {
        elem.data('state', false).animate({height:'40px'});
    }else{
        elem.data('state', true).animate({height:'100px'});
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rb2xb/)

Comment: what does `elem.data('state')` condition checks for ?? Curious as I never see this before.

Comment: It's just a flag, set on each element, to keep track of the state ?

Comment: oh yeah.. got it. :D I thought it's kinda return whether if element is  in *animating* state and whether to animate it or not.

Comment: Nope, whether the element is 40px or 100px high. It's a toggle function basically, as toggle() has been removed, at least that version of toggle, and now it only hides and shows elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `closest()`:

```
$('.clickme').toggle(function () {
    $(this).closest('.video').find('.text').animate({
        height: '100px'
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).closest('.video').find('.text').animate({
        height: '40px'
    });
});
```

Comment: This also works perfectly, what is the most efficient way to do this since all of the replies are great?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('.clickme').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent().siblings('.text').animate({height:'100px'});
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.text').animate({height:'40px'});
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I did not try the .siblings() part. Thank you, that really helped.